# Unit testing of gin's Context.Redirect works for GET response code but fails for POST response code (golang)

Tags: go, go-gin

I want my server to redirect a particular end point to another server. This end point can be either `GET`ted or `POST`ed.  The HTTP response code should be 302 in both cases. And if I use `curl` on this code, it does indeed show response code 302 in both cases, and `curl -L` follows the redirect properly. Whew.

*BUT*

my unit test uses the `httptest.NewRecorder()` to capture the information, but it only works for `GET` and not for `POST`.  So I need to figure out how to get the unit test to work, when I know that the actual redirect is working.  The fail test shows that the HTTP response code is 200 instead of 302 (`http.StatusFound`).

```
$ go run foo.go
POST code 200
GET code 302
```

Here's the self contained test.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
        context.Request = httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:23632/foobar", nil)
        context.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "http://foobar.com")

        print("POST code ",w.Code,"\n")
    }

    {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
        context.Request = httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:23632/foobar", nil)
        context.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "http://foobar.com")

        print("GET code ",w.Code,"\n")
    }
}
```

When I do CURL POST on the actual app (not shown), I see that it is working:

```
curl -v -XPOST localhost:23632/foobar
* About to connect() to localhost port 23632 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 23632 (#0)
> POST /foobar HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:23632
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://foobar.com
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Tue, 23 May 2023 22:38:42 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The workaround is to call `context.Writer.WriteHeaderNow` explicitly after `context.Redirect`.

#### Explanation

This is a corner case of using the gin context returned from `gin.CreateTestContext`.

For the GET request, gin will call `http.Redirect` finally, which will write a short HTML body (something like `<a href="http://foobar.com">Found</a>`) to the response, which in turn causes the status code to be written to the response.

While for the POST request, `http.Redirect` does not write the short HTML body, and the status code don't have the chance to be written to the response.

See [the implementation of http.Redirect](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e7a9ca0a53db4b4f357b5d3caaef65e44ce08a90/src/net/http/server.go#L2243-L2246). According to the source code, if the header `Content-Type` is set before, the GET request will have the same issue too:

```
  {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
    context.Request = httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:23632/foobar", nil)
+   context.Header("Content-Type", "text/html")
    context.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "http://foobar.com")
    print("GET code ", w.Code, "\n")
  }
```

The workaround is to call `context.Writer.WriteHeaderNow` explicitly:

```
  {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
    context.Request = httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:23632/foobar", nil)
    context.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "http://foobar.com")
+   context.Writer.WriteHeaderNow()

    print("POST code ", w.Code, "\n")
  }
```

gin itself uses the same workaround. See [TestContextRenderRedirectWithRelativePath](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/6a0556ed5a67d1d12ae3e7ea2c0121b6c3b894e2/context_test.go#L1115-L1127).

A real server app does not suffer from the same issue because `(*Engine).handleHTTPRequest` will call `WriteHeaderNow` for us (see [the source code](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/6a0556ed5a67d1d12ae3e7ea2c0121b6c3b894e2/gin.go#L621)). That's why I call it a corner case instead of a bug.

Comment: Thank you. I had noticed that the POST doesn't write the short HTML body, while the GET does, and I figure that was probably related. 
I've marked this as the Answer, as this is what I was looking for. My tests pass now.